PYTHON: Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
I'am enable to run my code via Python. The main problem of it is that, the error is plotting "Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)". Is the problem from my designed network or my dataloader?
Here is my code:
class SiameseNetwork(nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
    super(SiameseNetwork, self).__init__()
    self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(1, 8, kernel_size=3)
    self.pool = nn.MaxPool1d(2)
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(8 * 999, 128) 
    self.fc_out = nn.Linear(128, 1)

def shared_network(self, x):
    x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
    x = self.pool(x)
    x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)  # Aplatir la sortie
    x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
    x = self.fc_out(x)
    return x

def forward(self, x1, x2):
    out1 = self.shared_network(x1)
    out2 = self.shared_network(x2)
    return out1, out2

class SignalDataset(Dataset):
def __init__(self, signals):
    self.signals = signals

def __len__(self):
    return len(self.signals)

def __getitem__(self, index):
    sig0 = random.choice(self.signals)
    sig1 = random.choice(self.signals)

    max_length = 2000  # Mise à jour de la longueur maximale
    if sig0.shape[1] > max_length:
        sig0 = sig0[:, :max_length]
    if sig1.shape[1] > max_length:
        sig1 = sig1[:, :max_length]

    if len(sig0.shape) == 1:
        sig0 = sig0[None, :]
    if len(sig1.shape) == 1:
        sig1 = sig1[None, :]

    sig0 = torch.tensor(sig0, dtype=torch.float32)
    sig1 = torch.tensor(sig1, dtype=torch.float32)

    # Debugging print statements
    print(f"sig0 shape: {sig0.shape}, sig1 shape: {sig1.shape}")

    return sig0, sig1, torch.tensor(self.signals[index], dtype=torch.float32)


# Convert signals to PyTorch tensors and create dataset and dataloader
 def create_dataloader(signals):
dataset = SignalDataset(signals)
return DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=16, shuffle=True, num_workers=0)


class ContrastiveLoss(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, margin=2.0):
    super(ContrastiveLoss).__init__()
    self.margin = margin

def forward(self, out1, out2, label):
    euclidean_distance = F.pairwise_distance(out1, out2, keepdim=True)
    loss_constractive = torch.mean((1 - label) * torch.pow(euclidean_distance, 2) +
                                   (label) * torch.pow(torch.clamp(self.margin - 
             euclidean_distance, min=0.0), 2))

    return loss_constractive



# Example data loader
train_dataloader = create_dataloader(signals)
print(len(train_dataloader))
# Initialize model, criterion, and optimizer
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
model = SiameseNetwork().to((device))
criterion = ContrastiveLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
print(model)

counter = []
loss_history = []
iteration_number = 0
epochs = 5


for epoch in range(epochs):
model.train()

for i, (sig0, sig1, label) in enumerate(train_dataloader):
    print(f"sig0: {sig0.shape}, sig1: {sig1.shape}, label: {label.shape}")
    sig0, sig1, label = sig0.to(device), sig1.to(device), label.to(device)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    out1, out2 = model(sig0, sig1)
    print(f"out1: {out1.shape}, out2: {out2.shape}")

    loss_constrative = criterion(out1, out2, label)

    loss_constrative.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    if i % 10 == 0:
        print(f"Epoch number: {epoch}, || Current loss: {loss_constrative.item()}")
        iteration_number += 10

        counter.append(iteration_number)
        loss_history.append(loss_constrative.item())

Below is the error from my code:
Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
sig0: torch.Size([16, 1, 2000]), sig1: torch.Size([16, 1, 2000]), label: 
torch.Size([16, 1, 2000])

The issue is because the network parameters are high. The dataset size should not be s big deal in my opinion.

The code you've pasted is misindented. Please fix that.

Run Python with python -X dev your_script.py (dev mode) to enable (among other things) the faulthandler to see where your program is actually crashing.

@AKX It showing the error below. torch was upgraded but still printing the same problem, what should be the real problem at your opinion: (base) ➜  DataMaching python3 -X dev data_siamese.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/mac/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/ProjetBreathAnalysis/DataMaching/data_siamese.py", line 7, in 
import torch
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'

That is not the same problem as before (a SIGSEGV). That's you not having torch installed anymore.

I have solved the problem, thank you Sir @AKX

Glad I could help. You should self-answer with the steps you took to figure out what's wrong, and how you fixed it, so others with the same issue can get help too.
